# Protractor: Non angular login to angular site

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Before I can reach the site to be tested I have to visit a login (non-angular) page first

```
var url = 'http://localhost:9999/login?usern=bar';
browser.driver.get(url);
```

Although that is a non-angular page, passing the `?usern=bar` into the url the server gives an HTTP CODE of 302, and redirects to the page `/new-user`. Inside the `new-user` page I have to click a button before I can begin testing

But whatever I do I always get

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

There is something wrong in my flow, because I can see the `new-user` page, but the button is not clicked (and long after that the errors appear)

The spec file:

```
var Site = require('helper/site');

describe('Main', function {
    beforeAll(function () {
        return Site.login();
    });

    it('should show the main page', function () {
        epect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(/\/main/);
    });
});
```

Site.js:

```
function login() {
    browser.driver.get('http://localhost:9999/login?usern=bar');

    browser.driver.wait(function () {
        return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
            return /\/new-user/.test(url);
        });
    });

    element(by.css('.save')).click();
}

module.exports = {
    login: login
};
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *turn the sync off*:

```
describe('Main', function {
    beforeAll(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        return Site.login();
    });

    it('should show the main page', function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;

        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(/\/main/);
    });
});
```

Though, think of better places to turn it off and then on again once you are on the main page.

Comment: This is much better! Now it navigates to the main page. But then I still get the same timeout error. If, however, I remove the `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;` the test completes. Any suggestions why this happens ?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri hm, what if you add `browser.waitForAngular()` when you are on the main page? Thanks.

Comment: `browser.waitForAngular()` doesn't break it, as soon as I add `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;` (also in combination with waitForAngular) the test will not run, and a timeout is thrown

Comment: Got it! I have a ping service which uses $timeout over and over again. It is pointed out [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/973). Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I used browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) to turn off waiting for angular app. My app used O365 login.

```
public async HandleO365Login() {
        await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        await this.o365usernameTextBox.sendKeys(Constants.USER_EMAIL);
        await this.o365NextButton.click();
    }
```

You can turn it on after your angular app gets loaded.